# How to get UserTenantDomain as part of claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0. I would like to get UserTenantDomain as part of claim.

It is returning sometimes but not all the time.

Eg: Username: **sample@mail.com**
    UserTenantDomain : **tenant.com**

I set username as claim subject URI.
For some users it is returning **sample@mail.com@tenant.com** but for some users it is returning only **sample@mail.com**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Complete username is part of NAMEID in the SAML response. No need to look into the claims. If you use PAC4J then remove the subject claim URI from the SP claim configuration which means choose '---Select One---'. So the pac4j gives you the complete username in CommonProfile id field

```
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">sample@mail.com@tenant.com</saml2:NameID>
```